# Crafting my own event thrower in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, javascript-objects, dom-events

I know (mostly) how to react to the various events fired by that menagerie of objects living inside the DOM.

To notch things up a bit, I'd like to be able to fire my own bespoke events when appropriate, something I suppose I could pseudo-code as follow :

```
myObject = {
    prop:{ soAndSo }
    method : function(args){
        //do some stuff that takes forever
        "All done and ready, now tell the world"
    }
}
```

The idea being of course that some time down the road I can instantiate a myObject, then even later monitor its behaviour with something to the effect of

```
aMyObject.onmyevent = function(event){
    //do something appropriate for the circumstance
}
```

The thing is, I have no clue as to where to start regarding the part "now tell the world".

Will you point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a faux eventEmitter. Here is one I made while following a tutorial from Pluralsight called React and Flux for Angular Developers:  [Tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-flux-angular/table-of-contents)

To your question, you 'tell the world' by emitting the event, which is essentially calling all the active listeners you have.

```
// make your own emitter:

function EventEmitter () {
  // holds events buy type; ex:'ADD_TODO'
  this._events = {};
}

EventEmitter.prototype.on = function(type, listener) {
  // add events to listen for
  this._events[type] = this._events[type] || [];
  this._events[type].push(listener);
};

EventEmitter.prototype.emit = function(type) {
  // emit event base on type
  if (this._events[type]) {
    this._event[type].forEach(function(listener) {
      // call listeners for events:
      listener();
    });
  }
};

EventEmitter.prototype.removeListener = function(type, listern) {
  if (this._events[type]) {
    this._events[type].splice(this._events[type].indexOf(listener), 1)
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answers my question perfectly.

Comment: Great! Can you mark this as the correct answer? Thanks!!

Comment: Better late than never : I finally found the check mark.